# Why does my for-loop only work when I slow it down?

Tags: go

This code prints 0, but if I insert time.Sleep(0) into the updater
loop, it prints >1

```
var Nonce int = 0

func Updater(){
    for{
        Nonce += 1
    }
}

func main(){
    go Updater()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("%d\n",Nonce)
}
```

Comment: Don't use `time.Sleep` to manage concurrency. Use channels/`WaitGroup`s/`Mutex`es.

Comment: I'm not using Sleep to do that -- it just exposes the problem here.

Comment: You are, in `main()`.

Comment: Your code has a data race: you read `Nonce` in the `main` goroutine, and you write it in another goroutine, without synchronization. The result is undefined. You must use synchronization.

Comment: As noted elsewhere, there's a data race. It might be instructive to run the program with the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html).

Comment: Also, `Updater` is a busy loop, which is nearly always an error, and will eventually block the GC and the scheduler.

Comment: `Nonce`? Seriously? XD

Answer (score 2):

`nonce.go`:

> ```
> package main
>
> import (
>   "fmt"
>   "time"
> )
>
> var Nonce int = 0
>
> func Updater() {
>   for {
>       Nonce += 1
>   }
> }
>
> func main() {
>   go Updater()
>   time.Sleep(time.Second)
>   fmt.Printf("%d\n", Nonce)
> }
> ```

---

First, the Go gc compiler is an optimizing compiler. There is no synchronization between the goroutines. Therefore the `Nonce += 1` statement is elided, and the value of `Nonce` stays at zero. See the compiled code:

```
$ go build nonce.go
$ objdump -d -S ./nonce
```

Output:

```
var Nonce int = 0

func Updater() {
    for {
        Nonce += 1
  4888f0:   eb fe                   jmp    4888f0 <main.Updater>
  4888f2:   cc                      int3   
    }
}
```

---

Second, if we run the Go data race detector, some optimization is suppressed. Therefore,a data race condition is detected for the `Nonce` variable. The results of a data race are undefined.

```
$ go run -race nonce.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x0000005f2648 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/nonce.go:19 +0x63

Previous write at 0x0000005f2648 by goroutine 6:
  main.Updater()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/nonce.go:12 +0x56

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/nonce.go:17 +0x46
==================
42758109
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function spins up a goroutine to run `Updater` and then immediately exits. Without the sleep, `Updater` doesn't have time to start and do its thing. This code is *racy* - it will sometimes work as you expect and sometimes won't. You have to synchronize the `Updater` goroutine with `main` somehow, using a channel or a wait group for example.

Moreover, you're updating the `Nonce` global in one goroutine and reading it in another - this is a data race. You'll need to synchronize access to this var with a mutex.

---

Here's a more correct variant of your code, though it's still rather non-sensical (why do you need a goroutine to run the busy loop?)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var Nonce int = 0

func Updater(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        Nonce += 1
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go Updater(&wg)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", Nonce)
}
```

Here we use a `WaitGroup` for the `Updater` to signal "I'm done" to the main goroutine, which only then checks the value of `Nonce`. This program should print "1000" every time